# Windows delete files in multiple directories files order then n hours using bat

Tags: windows, batch-file

I got for example n folders 
{C:/tst1,C:/tst2,C:/tst3,C:/tst1} 
and in those folders I need delete files which were created like >5 hours  I know forfile can't delete with hours option what else could I use ?

Comment: tried that answer didn't helped

Comment: There are three answers in that question and two of them I have used successfully at my job.  Update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: Mofi, also posted a link to an answer in one of his comments. His code is normally very solid.

Comment: You could also use [Dave Benham's JTimeStamp](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7523) to calculate a time difference.  Use a `FOR` command to get the time stamp of the file.  Then use the date and time variables for the current time and feed it to JTimeStamp to get the time difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably utilise `PowerShell` from your batch file for this.

Given your provided information you could try the following:

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "GCI 'C:\tst*\*'|?{!$_.PSIsContainer -And ($_.LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddHours(-5))}|Rm -Wh"&Pause
```

This will not delete the files, *for your protection*, it will just show you those it would delete.
If you are satisfied with the output you can replace `-Wh"&Pause` at the end of the line with `-Fo"`.